# how to compare three groups (significant different higher and significant different lower)

Tags: r, statistical-significance, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons

I have a Control group with two replicate and two treated group with two replicate. I want to know how I can identify the sample that are significantly different between control and treated 1 (higher expression) while significant different between control and treated 2 (lower expression)

This is an example data

```
df<-structure(list(C1 = c(0.003926348, 0.001642442, 6.72e-05, 0.000314789, 
0.00031372, 0.000196342, 0.01318432, 8.86e-05, 0.005671017, 0.003616196, 
0.026635645, 0.001136402, 0.000161111, 0.005777738, 0.000145104, 
0.000996546, 4.27e-05, 0.000114159, 0.001152384, 0.002860251, 
0.000284873), C2 = c(0.003901373, 0.001526195, 6.3e-05, 0.000387266, 
0.000312458, 0.000256647, 0.012489205, 0.00013071, 0.005196136, 
0.003059834, 0.024624562, 0.001025486, 0.000144964, 0.005659078, 
0.000105755, 0.000844871, 5.88e-05, 0.000118831, 0.000999354, 
0.002153167, 0.000214486), T1 = c(0.003646894, 0.001484503, 4.93e-05, 
0.00036715, 0.000333378, 0.000244199, 0.010286787, 6.48e-05, 
0.006180042, 0.00387491, 0.025428464, 0.001075376, 0.000122088, 
0.005448152, 0.000103301, 0.000974826, 4.32e-05, 0.000109876, 
0.001030364, 0.002777244, 0.000221169), T2 = c(0.00050388, 0.001135969, 
0.000113829, 2.14e-06, 0.00010293, 0.000315704, 0.01160593, 8.46e-05, 
0.004495437, 0.003062559, 0.018662663, 0.002096675, 0.000214814, 
0.002177849, 8.61e-05, 0.001057254, 3.27e-05, 0.000115822, 0.008133257, 
0.021657018, 0.000261339), G1 = c(0.001496712, 0.001640965, 0.000129124, 
3.02e-06, 0.000122839, 0.000305686, 0.01378774, 0.000199637, 
0.00534668, 0.00300097, 0.023290941, 0.002595433, 0.000262479, 
0.002926346, 0.000125655, 0.001302624, 4.89e-05, 0.000122862, 
0.009851791, 0.017621282, 0.000197561), G2 = c(0.00114337, 0.001285636, 
0.000122848, 2.46e-06, 9.1e-05, 0.000288897, 0.012288087, 0.000122286, 
0.002575368, 0.002158011, 0.022008677, 0.002017026, 0.000241754, 
0.003340175, 0.00013424, 0.001517655, 4.78e-05, 0.000110353, 
0.008293286, 0.018999466, 0.000191129)), .Names = c("C1", "C2", 
"T1", "T2", "G1", "G2"), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "PP", 
"TT", "EE", "FF", "AS"), class = "data.frame")
```

The first two columns are the control 
the second two columns are the treated 1
the third two columns are the treated 2

Comment: Please keep in mind what "sample"  means in statistics. When you say "sample", do you mean "observation"? What are the rows in your data?

Comment: @Roland Yes, it means observations

Comment: From your explanation I can infer the C1+T1 are the control and treatment for group 1, C2+T2 are control and treatment for group 2. What is G1 and G2?

Comment: @Guilherme Marthe  C1 and C2 are control (one replicate) ,T1 and T2 are the first treatment (one replicate) and G1 and G2 are the second treatment (one replicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of questions you could be asking.  One is whether there is a treatment difference as a whole, and the other is which individuals responded to treatment. TLDR at the bottom.

**Overall Treatment Difference**

Given you have repeated measures of each subject, I would recommend using a mixed model design instead of a classical ANOVA or any $t$-tests.  This allows for different intercept values for each observation.  This will also control for any multiplicity by modeling the differences between control and treatments simultaneously.

In R and using your data, I would do this:

```
library(nlme)
library(reshape2)
df$obs <- rownames(df)
data.lme <- melt(data=df, id.vars='obs', value.name='score', variable.name='trt')
data.lme$trt.lvl <- substr(data.lme$trt, 1, 1)
fit.lme <- lme(score ~ trt.lvl, random=~1|obs, data=data.lme)
summary(fit.lme)
```

This gives an output of:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data.lme 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -1041.937 -1027.876 525.9684

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | obs
        (Intercept)    Residual
StdDev: 0.005667867 0.002410868

Fixed effects: score ~ trt.lvl 
                   Value    Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.0031333349 0.0012915635 103 2.4260015  0.0170
trt.lvlG    0.0007085406 0.0005260946 103 1.3467933  0.1810
trt.lvlT    0.0001948673 0.0005260946 103 0.3704036  0.7118
 Correlation: 
         (Intr) trt.lG
trt.lvlG -0.204       
trt.lvlT -0.204  0.500

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.457389008 -0.204662471 -0.000118683  0.106147927  4.551752397 

Number of Observations: 126
Number of Groups: 21
```

So for the data you posted, there doesn't appear to be any difference in the two treatment groups compared to the control, when accounting for repeated measures of individuals and using the usual $\alpha=0.05$ level of significance.

**Which individuals respond to treatment - Edited responding to comments**

After rereading some of your comments and of others (thank you @guilhermemarthe for encouraging me to think more about this), it seems like you want to know which had a positive mean change for Treatment G and a negative mean change for Treatment T.  Further, you want to know whether these changes were statistically significant on a per-observation basis.  *Statistics isn't well designed to identify "significant differences" in individual observable units*.  Rather it focuses on changes in (statistical) samples and extrapolates those changes to populations of interest.  I think by trying to find "significant" changes on the per-individual level, you're asking the wrong question.

But pressing forward with that as best as I can discern, if you want to identify what samples went up vs went down, that is simply an assessment of the change in means for each sample from control to respective treatment.  In R, that looks like this:

```
data.mean <- dcast(data.lme, obs~trt.lvl, value.var='score', fun.aggregate=mean)
data.mdiff <- data.frame(obs=data.mean$obs,
                         trt.g=data.mean$G - data.mean$C,
                         trt.t=data.mean$T - data.mean$C)
data.mdiff$resp.g <- data.mdiff$trt.g > 0
data.mdiff$resp.t <- data.mdiff$trt.t < 0
```

The data frame then looks like:

```
obs         trt.g         trt.t resp.g resp.t
1    A -0.0025938195 -0.0018384735  FALSE   TRUE
2   AS -0.0000553345 -0.0000084255  FALSE   TRUE
3    B -0.0001210180 -0.0002740825  FALSE   TRUE
4    C  0.0000608860  0.0000164645   TRUE  FALSE
5    D -0.0003482875 -0.0001663825  FALSE   TRUE
6    E -0.0002061695 -0.0000949350  FALSE   TRUE
7   EE  0.0079966695  0.0035059415   TRUE  FALSE
8    F  0.0000707970  0.0000534570   TRUE  FALSE
9   FF  0.0158036650  0.0097104220   TRUE  FALSE
10   G  0.0002011510 -0.0018904040   TRUE   TRUE
11   H  0.0000513065 -0.0000349550   TRUE   TRUE
12   I -0.0014725525 -0.0000958370  FALSE   TRUE
13   J -0.0007585245  0.0001307195  FALSE  FALSE
14   K -0.0029802945 -0.0035845400  FALSE   TRUE
15   L  0.0012252855  0.0005050815   TRUE  FALSE
16   M  0.0000990790  0.0000154135   TRUE  FALSE
17   N -0.0025851475 -0.0019054075  FALSE   TRUE
18   O  0.0000045180 -0.0000307290   TRUE   TRUE
19   P  0.0004894310  0.0000953315   TRUE  FALSE
20  PP -0.0000024000 -0.0000128000  FALSE   TRUE
21  TT  0.0000001125 -0.0000036460   TRUE   TRUE
```

To sort:

```
data.mdiff$ord <- data.mdiff$resp.g & data.mdiff$resp.t
data.mdiff <- data.mdiff[order(data.mdiff$ord, decreasing=T),]
```

The flag in the `resp.g` and `resp.t` variable indicates which samples went up vs which went down, respective to the treatment applied.  If you refine your definition of what "response" is, then you can adjust the thresholds for change in means accordingly.  Any attempt to find "significance" of individual observations would only result in finding samples that deviate from some pre-defined distributional assumption (which is precisely what outlier detection is).  I don't think you're looking for that.

**Conclusion - TLDR**

I think you're asking the wrong question to begin with.  It seems like you need to first address the question of whether there actually is an overall treatment difference instead of trying to identify what samples "statistically responded."  *To look for responders necessarily assumes that response to treatment is real, and there doesn't seem to be evidence for that.*  That overall analysis (the first I presented) would tell you whether your intervention was effective in the (statistical) sample you observed.  Once you establish what "response" looks like, then you can start determining whether individual samples meet that criterion without concerning yourself with significance.

Comment: Thanks for your message but I want to identify those observations that are significantly different in the first treatment (higher values) and significantly different in the second treatment (lower values) does it make sense? if you help me I will accept your answer

Comment: I'm actually concerned that your treatments don't have a significant effect overall, before I would consider any individual sample as being "higher" or "lower."  Since there is no overall effect for either treatment, any "higher" or "lower" sample is likely due to random variation, and not any true response to that treatment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as far as I know, you are not able to use the approach you suggest to compare between treatments, since the comparison is against the control group (or treatment level C in your data frame). Am I correct?

Comment: The fixed effects (`trt.lvlG` and `trt.lvlT`) and the associated significance are mean changes relative to the baseline group (`trt.lvlC`).  So those mean differences are the comparison between the control group and the respective treatment groups.

Comment: But the significance is calculated having the null hypothesis relative to the control group.   

Unless something different is going on in the significance calculation due to mixed effects model that I am unaware of, you shouldn't use the significance in testing for differences between control X treatment to  asses for differences between treatment A X treatment B

Comment: My understanding of the OPs needs are that they are making comparisons between each of the two treatments and the control group.  If a comparisons between treatments themselves is desired, that can be easily accomplished through changing the contrasts in the factor.  Re-running the model with those contrasts would give the estimated mean difference and significance between treatments.

Comment: @Ashe  I want to know your approach, you are free to make a simulated data. can you ?

Comment: Added changes according to these comments.

Comment: @Ashe  thanks for updating it, how statistically the second part is valid? because the conclusion is based on the mean of each set (control or treated) is it right to do this?

Comment: The second part is valid because you've *predetermined* what your "response" is.  If you've determined that response is a change in mean >0 and that's not random noise, then you can say those units responded.  If you haven't determined what response is yet, which I'm getting the impression that's the case, then that needs to be done first.  You can't determine what response is *and* find which individuals responded in the same dataset.  That would lead to an inflated proportion of responders.

Comment: @Ashe I accepted your answer. Is it possible to add the part that you sort the samples which are True in first treated and False in the second ?

Comment: I assume you mean samples where the change in mean went up in G and down in T.  If so, that sort is added.  Again, I want to emphasize, unless you *know* that response is change in mean >0, I wouldn't talk about truths.  Just talk about observed changes in mean values.

Answer (score 0):

The way you phrase the question makes it seem like you want to compare observations across treatments. However, if the 3 groups are separate, it doesn't make sense to compare single observations. Instead, you probably want to look at whether the group means are significantly different.

One option is to use two Two-Sample T-Tests to compare the control group to each of the treatment groups. Building on your R code:

```
# Combine Replicates   
Control <- c(df$C1,df$C2)
Treatment1 <- c(df$T1,df$T2)
Treatment2 <- c(df$G1,df$G2)

# Two Sample T-test for Control Group and Treatment 1 Group
t.test(Control,Treatment1)
# Two Sample T-test for Control Group and Treatment 2 Group
t.test(Control,Treatment2)
```

You could also perform ANOVA:

```
# ANOVA
groups = factor(rep(c('C','T1','T2'), each = 42))
data <- c(Control,Treatment1,Treatment2)
mod <- lm(data~groups)
anova(mod)
```

For this example, the immediate results indicate that there is not a significant difference in the group means. However, you need to keep in mind that the normality assumption is severely violated (as can be seen by plotting the 3 groups). An alternative test may be more appropriate.

Comment: can you tell me your alternative method? I want those observations that are significantly changed in the treatment versus control (higher values) while they are significantly different in the second treatment (lower values)